# List filtering failure

Tags: 2010

I was encountered a problem of standard functionality of Sharepoint2010: I'm using items filtering in a list and it stops working for unknown reasons.

**Step1.** In some list I'm applying filter by "Person" (type of column "Choise").

After the first filter applying - all is ok.

**Step2:** already being in filtered list I'm changing filtered value by doing the same 2 clicks.
All is ok too.

**Step3:** Then I'm trying to change filtered value again and - **I got nothing for filtering**. Suddenly.

This failure occurs in several lists, not only in one
and filtering "fails" only for certain columns.
Sometimes after the first filter applying filter dropbox shows not all of available items...

Any suggestions / advices will be appreciated.

additional info: MasterPage is default, ajax/js scripting - not used.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your columns term sets?  Most columns will only show you content that exists while a term set will allow you to filter by any term - some of which may not exist.

Also, filters applied via columns headings are cumulative - so having applied a filter to one column you will get less options in another column.

Comment: I've found that the problem is in the incorrect url

Comment: .../AllItems.aspx?View={7996F620-DEEA-49E1-AFC9-DA3A04014E21}&FilterField1=Person%5f&FilterValue1=somevalue1&Filter=1  --- works fine

Comment: but after the second filtering the url string becomes look like this: ../AllItems.aspx?View={7996F620-DEEA-49E1-AFC9-DA3A04014E21}&FilterField1=Person%5F&FilterValue1=somevalue1&FilterField2=Person%5f&FilterValue2=somevalue2

Comment: means, instead of normal flow (just changhe the FilterValue1) SP for unknown reasons generates additional "FilterField2" with "FilterValue2"...

Comment: and it brokes the filtering

Comment: This is normal - it is what I meant above by cumulative filtering.  Each time you click on a column header to filter it adds that filter to the others.